# Why using cat | grep to search matched text is super slow

Tags: performance, command-line, grep, cat

I met a really strange issue in command line tool. Basically I was trying to search matched words and get the text from a file. So I have file1 with 80,000 words:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
...
```

And I have file2 with 600,000 lines of texts:

```
id: hhh, address: xxxx, content: yyyy
id: aaa, address: zzzz, content: eeee
id: jjj, address: qqqq, content: oooo
id: ccc, address: nnnn, content: tttt
...
```

I need to find the texts in file2 which contains the words in file1, so the output is like:

```
id: aaa, address: zzzz, content: eeee
id: ccc, address: nnnn, content: tttt
...
```

Now I was using command: `cat file2 | grep -f file1 > newfile.` I also tested the method and it works very well and there's nothing strange with its running speed. 
However, when I ran this command on that real files, it was super slow... till now it has been running for 12 hours and the command in terminal's still running! And when I checked in the newfile, there're only 2000 lines of texts generated, which means if I need to get the whole result of 80,000 lines I need 40 times of 12 hours, which is absolutely ridiculous.

Also, I tried to do the experiment on file2, the 600,000 lines of text. I ran a command like `cat file2 | grep -w 'aaa'`, it gets result immediately less than one second. I also tried it with a file with a couple of words, it also gets immediately. So I don't understand, why it took forever for the 80,000 words. Even if it takes a second that long for searching every single word, it still only takes less than 20 hours, which is still much faster than current case I met...Can anyone give me a hint please?

I

Comment: [UUoCA](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html) try `grep -f file1 file2 > newfile`

Comment: I tried this it's also very slow. But thank you for the help anyway:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code for searching for each of 80,000 lines in each of the 600,000 lines is taking a toll.

- Unconditional change: use `grep -f file1 file2` (no `cat`).  Probably a minor performance gain, but it saves copying the big file once.
- Probable: add `-F` to suppress wild-card searches. This may avoid 80,000 copies of compiled regexes which are actually simple searches.

  ```
  grep -F -f file1 file2
  ```
- Look up the `-w` and `-x` options to GNU `grep`. They may simplify the searches.
- Split the workload: break the 80,000 line file into 80 files of 1000 lines each; run the command 80 times.

The last option is something of a 'counsel of despair'.  If the other options don't speed things up, this may get you closer to sane performance (and at least you'll be able to time each set of lines searched for to get an idea how long it will run).

Comment: Thank you I was just trying to split the file1 into 7 portions, and each one takes roughly two minutes to get the results. But now I tried your command and it works for the 80,000 sized file! Thank you so much!